# Convert a C char * to .Net String then to byte[]

Tags: c#, .net, types, interop

I am having a data conversion issue that need your help.

My project is an `InterOp` between **C** and C#, all the data from **C** is `char *` type, the data itself could be binary or displayable chars, I.e. each byte is in 0x00 to 0xFF range.

I am using Data `marshal::PtrToStringAnsi` to convert the `char*` to `String^` in `CLI code`, but I found some bytes value changed. for example C382 converted to C32C. I guess it is possibly because `ANSI` is only capable of converting `7-bit char`, but `82` is over the range? Can anyone explain why and what is the best way?

Basically what I want to do is, I don't need any encoding conversion, I just want to convert any char * face value to a string, e.g. if `char *p = "ABC"` I want to `String ^s="ABC"` as well, if `*p="C382"`(represents binary value) I also want `^s="C382"`.

Inside my .NET code, two subclasses will take the input string that either represents binary data or real string, if it is binary it will convert `"C382" to byte[]=0xC3 0x82;`

When reading back the data, C382 will be fetched from database as binary data, eventually it need be converted to `char* "C382"`.

Does anybody have similar experience how to do these in both directions? I tried many ways, they all seem to be encode ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Marshal` class will do this for you.

When converting from `char*` to `byte[]` you need to pass the pointer and the buffer length to the managed code. Then you can do this:

```
byte[] FromNativeArray(IntPtr nativeArray, int len)
{
    byte[] retval = new byte[len];
    Marshal.Copy(nativeArray, retval, 0, len);
    return retval;
}
```

And in the other direction there's nothing much to do. If you have a `byte[]` then you can simply pass that to your DLL function that expects to receive a char*.

**C++**

```
void ReceiveBuffer(char* arr, int len);
```

**C#**

```
[DllImport(...)]
static extern void ReceiveBuffer(byte[] arr, int len);
....
ReceiveBuffer(arr, arr.Length);
```

Comment: Thanks David.I tried Marshal.Copy before my post, there are two issues for me. 1) I want to convert IntPtr to String first, as the .net superclass takes string as input type, one subclass is to process binary data and another is to process text string. 2) If I remembered correctly it seemed Copy does encoding conversion behind the scense, i.e. IntPtr to String( String is always double-byte).

Comment: Don't use `string`. `Marshal.Copy` does not encoding. The overload I have used here is equivalent to `memcpy`. As soon as you use string you will be forcing encoding into play. You explicitly state that you don't want to transform the data with encodings. So don't use string, and do use `byte[]`.

Comment: Thanks David again. I will have a try.

Comment: It is working perfectly. Last question David, why don't need marshalling from byte[] to char * in ReceiveBuffer? apparently in C++ we allocate memory for char * arr, right? as byte[] and char * are in different heap.

Comment: The p/invoke marshaller will pin the array for you and your C++ code can copy it into its own buffer. What the C++ code can't do is remember the address of the buffer and then use that later. Because the managed memory might have gone.